# XML XQuery Find sub nodes

Tags: sql-server, xml, filter, nodes, xquery

I have a 20k line XML file in a SQL table with XML data type.

Below is subsection of the file.

I need to find all System nodes for a particular DF ID

Here is my query, the query returns all system nodes not the system nodes for DF Id=1.

```
select station, 
  x.y.value('@id[1]','int') AS DFR_Id,
  z.y.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(128)') AS elem_name,
  z.y.value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS elem_text
from DME_Settings_Baseline e 
OUTER APPLY e.configxml.nodes('SubStation/DFs/DF') as X(Y)
OUTER APPLY e.configxml.nodes('SubStation/ DFs/DF/System/*') as Z(Y)
WHERE X.Y.value('@id[1]','int')=1'
```

---

```
<SubStation id="10" name="West">
<DFs>
<DF id="1">
  <IPAddress>155.100.1.1</IPAddress>
  <System>
    <DfrId>1</DfrId>
    <RecordingDeviceId>M9000</RecordingDeviceId>
    <SampleRate>4800</SampleRate>
    <LineFrequency>60</LineFrequency>
    <ExportRate>60</ExportRate>
    <ACount>56</ACount>
    <DigitalsCount>928</DigitalsCount>
    <PrefaultTime>500</PrefaultTime>
    <PostfaultTime>500</PostfaultTime>
    <LtrPrefaultTime>40</LtrPrefaultTime>
    <LtrPostfaultTime>40</LtrPostfaultTime>
    <ChatterLimit>20</ChatterLimit>
    <ChatterRate>2.0</ChatterRate>
    <TriggerLimit>500</TriggerLimit>
    <DatabaseDataType>BINARY</DatabaseDataType>
  </System>
</DF>
<DF id="2">
  <IPAddress>155.100.1.1</IPAddress>
  <System>
    <DfrId>2</DfrId>
    <RecordingDeviceId>M9000</RecordingDeviceId>
    <SampleRate>4800</SampleRate>
    <LineFrequency>60</LineFrequency>
    <ExportRate>60</ExportRate>
    <ACount>56</ACount>
    <DigitalsCount>928</DigitalsCount>
    <PrefaultTime>500</PrefaultTime>
    <PostfaultTime>500</PostfaultTime>
    <LtrPrefaultTime>40</LtrPrefaultTime>
    <LtrPostfaultTime>40</LtrPostfaultTime>
    <ChatterLimit>20</ChatterLimit>
    <ChatterRate>2.0</ChatterRate>
    <TriggerLimit>400</TriggerLimit>
    <DatabaseDataType>BINARY</DatabaseDataType>
    <Ps>S</Ps>
  </System>
</DF>
```

Comment: *"it does not work."* doesn't help us help you. Nor does a link to an image of data. What does "not work" mean? Does it produce unexpected results, undesired behaviour, an error, causes your PC to suffer a melt down? XML is text, so post the data as `text`. Then we cam consume it. What are your expected results here?

Comment: it returns all system nodes for both DF ID 1 & 2 not just the system nodes or DF ID = 1. how do I just return the system nodes for DF ID=1

Comment: Take the time to [edit] your question and improve it, @Angie .

Comment: Hey Larnu, I modified my question. Is it clear now? Also, it cuts off the last 2 close nodes for DFs & Substation.

Comment: Doesn't SQL Server allow predicates e.g. `nodes('/SubStation/DFs/DF[@id = "1"]/System/*')`? For the `x.y.value('@id[1]','int') AS DFR_Id` it seems you could as well navigate up from e.g. `z.y.value('../../@id', 'int') AS DFR_Id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following.

> SQL

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, configxml XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl (configxml) VALUES
(N'<SubStation id="10" name="West">
    <DFs>
        <DF id="1">
            <IPAddress>155.100.1.1</IPAddress>
            <System>
                <DfrId>1</DfrId>
                <RecordingDeviceId>M9000</RecordingDeviceId>
                <SampleRate>4800</SampleRate>
                <LineFrequency>60</LineFrequency>
                <ExportRate>60</ExportRate>
                <ACount>56</ACount>
                <DigitalsCount>928</DigitalsCount>
                <PrefaultTime>500</PrefaultTime>
                <PostfaultTime>500</PostfaultTime>
                <LtrPrefaultTime>40</LtrPrefaultTime>
                <LtrPostfaultTime>40</LtrPostfaultTime>
                <ChatterLimit>20</ChatterLimit>
                <ChatterRate>2.0</ChatterRate>
                <TriggerLimit>500</TriggerLimit>
                <DatabaseDataType>BINARY</DatabaseDataType>
            </System>
        </DF>
        <DF id="2">
            <IPAddress>155.100.1.1</IPAddress>
            <System>
                <DfrId>2</DfrId>
                <RecordingDeviceId>M9000</RecordingDeviceId>
                <SampleRate>4800</SampleRate>
                <LineFrequency>60</LineFrequency>
                <ExportRate>60</ExportRate>
                <ACount>56</ACount>
                <DigitalsCount>928</DigitalsCount>
                <PrefaultTime>500</PrefaultTime>
                <PostfaultTime>500</PostfaultTime>
                <LtrPrefaultTime>40</LtrPrefaultTime>
                <LtrPostfaultTime>40</LtrPostfaultTime>
                <ChatterLimit>20</ChatterLimit>
                <ChatterRate>2.0</ChatterRate>
                <TriggerLimit>400</TriggerLimit>
                <DatabaseDataType>BINARY</DatabaseDataType>
                <Ps>S</Ps>
            </System>
        </DF>
    </DFs>
</SubStation>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT t.c.value('@id','INT') AS DFR_Id,
    z.y.value('local-name(.)', 'NVARCHAR(128)') AS elem_name,
    z.y.value('text()[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS elem_text
FROM @tbl AS e 
    CROSS APPLY e.configxml.nodes('/SubStation/DFs/DF') as t(c)
    CROSS APPLY t.c.nodes('System/*') as z(y)
WHERE t.c.value('@id','INT')=1;
```

> Output

```
+--------+-------------------+-----------+
| DFR_Id |     elem_name     | elem_text |
+--------+-------------------+-----------+
|      1 | DfrId             | 1         |
|      1 | RecordingDeviceId | M9000     |
|      1 | SampleRate        | 4800      |
|      1 | LineFrequency     | 60        |
|      1 | ExportRate        | 60        |
|      1 | ACount            | 56        |
|      1 | DigitalsCount     | 928       |
|      1 | PrefaultTime      | 500       |
|      1 | PostfaultTime     | 500       |
|      1 | LtrPrefaultTime   | 40        |
|      1 | LtrPostfaultTime  | 40        |
|      1 | ChatterLimit      | 20        |
|      1 | ChatterRate       | 2.0       |
|      1 | TriggerLimit      | 500       |
|      1 | DatabaseDataType  | BINARY    |
+--------+-------------------+-----------+
```

Comment: @Angie, good to hear the the proposed solution is working for you. Please don't forget to mark it as Answer.

Comment: Hey Yitzhak, I am new to stackOverflow. How do I mark the solution as answered? Thanks. Angie

Comment: @Angie. You simply need to mark an answer as correct (the green check image). 
Click the green outlined checkmark to the left of the answer that solved your problem. This marks the answer as "accepted"

Comment: @Angie, Also, please connect with me on LinkedIn.